# How to delete cell from sage notebook?

Tags: sage

How to delete cell from sage notebook?

Any click is just creating something, no way to delete:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the legacy Sage notebook, you delete a cell by removing all content and then doing backspace/delete.  To quote [this tutorial](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/prep/Intro-Tutorial.html#sagenbcommands),

> If for some reason you need to remove or delete an input cell, just delete all the text inside of it, and then press backspace in the now-empty cell.